# How to make android view zoomable?

Tags: android

I have a Table Layout with buttons and I need a possibility to zoom it in. I have a lot of buttons inside layout so I need a good performance solution.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you would like to "zoom in" and how?  Also please consider adding relevant code (xml layout). Thx.

Comment: I said that I want to zoom table layout with buttons, meaning I want to make buttons bigger. What exactly do you want me to specify? Why do you need the xml with layout and buttons to answer this question?

Comment: mostly, due to this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also, answeringquestions in comment are ok, but is so sweet when you edit your question and add that relevant information so that no one has to read a comment trail to get the gist of what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use these methods:

```
layout.setPivotX(0);
layout.setPivotY(0);
layout.setScaleX(scale); // 1 is normal (no scale)
layout.setScaleY(scale);
```